# Calling a function on an enum constant obtained by values()

Tags: java, enums, interface, casting, iteration

I'm trying to generalise some code by iterating over all constants of an enum to receive the same specific argument from each one.

Specifically I have an enum **P** with some constants **A,B,C**.
Each of these constants is itself an enum and implements an interface **I** that defines a function **f**.
**P.values()** gives me an array **P[] A = {A,B,C}**, however I can't call **A[i].f()** since **A[i]** is of course of type **P** which doesn't implement **I**.
Now in my understanding a function can return an interface, but I can not instantiate it and therefore can't cast to it.
Should I overwrite **values()** for **P** to return **I[]**? If so, how would I do that since I can't cast to **I**? Or is there another solution?

I am working in eclipse but assuming that it's complaints are indicative of a true mistake, not just eclipse not recognising types.
Since I'm somewhat new to Java I would also appreciate any links to resources that explain the underlying rules of type matching/checking.

Comment: share your code

Comment: I think I'm missing something. Does your `enum` implement the relevant interface? If so, you should be able to call the function `f` directly. If not, perhaps the `enum` should implement `I`.

Comment: Every enum constant should implement the same interface `I`? `enum P implements I { A(fa), B(fb), C(fc); public final F f; P(F f) { this.f = f; } ...}`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you describe - perhaps I have misunderstood your question though. If so please explain further.

```
interface I {
    void f ();
}

enum P implements I{
    A,
    B,
    C {
        // Demonstrate enum-specific implementation.
        @Override
        public void f () {
            System.out.println("SEEEEEE!");
        }
    };

    // By default `f` prints the name of the enum.
    @Override
    public void f () {
        System.out.println(name());
    }
}

public void test() throws Exception {
    for ( I i : P.values()) {
        i.f();
    }
}
```